# Is it possible to recover waste heat from a boiler?

Tags: heating, hvac, energy-efficiency, boiler

I did a google search and came back with industrial products, but no residential prosucts.

I have a System 2000 boiler and hot water tank. When the furnace is firing, the temp of the exhaust through the flue is around 400 degrees.

That seems like a horrible waste of heat.

Same thing with the dryer. It throws heat right outdoors, which also seems like a waste. (not really concerned with humid air, as it is winter and I have to run a humidifier anyway).

Is there any "safe" method to do recover waste heat from a boiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into condensing boilers that do just that and capture a lot of heat that would normally fly out of the chimney. In fact they vent through a PVC pipe producing a lukewarm steam and have efficiency as high as 96%

So if your current boiler is close to the end of its usefull life, then upgrade might be a sensible investment.

However it's not a bad idea to evaluate your house as a whole. If its poorly insulated and drafty, then that should be addressed as well.

A lot of states and some energy companies offer free or very cheap home efficiency auditing and insulation programs.

Comment: Yeah - the boiler was purchased/installed new 2 years ago: http://www.energykinetics.com/ - so it's a good boiler, but I hate seeing that thermometer in the flue vent get up to 400 degrees - it breaks my cheap heart

Comment: I am by no means an expert on hvac, but after looking at the energy kinetics website I felt like I just watched a billy maze infomercial. Claims that afue rating is wrong seem fishy. So maybe their boiler is just not that efficient

Comment: yeah, now that I'm reading that - it does seem odd. If we had known we ere going to put in a pellet stove, I would have kept the old boiler and put in a gas on demand hot water system, because the boiler is barely firing (only for hot water and the back bedrooms)